# 301 redirect with rewrite for my domain

Tags: .htaccess

URL : http://domainname.com/index.php?p=top-games

I need to redirect(**301 redirect**) this as http://domainname.com/top-games

How I do this using htaccess file? Please can any one give me the htaccess code.

Thanks

Currently I use following code also to **rewrite**. Now I want to **redirect** also.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # 301 redirects should come first
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

    # remove www from domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was worked. And I need another help also. How to redirect www to non www domain. ( www.domian.com to domain.com)

Comment: I will add that rule in few minutes.

Comment: @Raplus: Added rule for www to non-www